# LINQ and Sorting into sequential Collection with random access capability

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

I have this code:

```
SortedList<int, SortedList<int, SimulationPoint>> sl = new SortedList<int, SortedList<int, SimulationPoint>>();

for(int i=0; i<source.Reflections+1; i++)
{
    sl.Add(i, new SortedList<int, SimulationPoint>());
}

var q = source.SimulationResult.Where(x => !x.Value.hasHit);

foreach (var qa in q) 
{  
    sl[qa.Key.Item2].Add(qa.Key.Item1, qa.Value); 
}
```

I wanted to generate a sorted output of the collection `source.SimulationResult`, which is a `Dictionary<(int, int), SimulationPoint>`. (This dictionary was generated using a `Parallel.For()` loop, so all the items are in random order.)

Dictionary Key: Just the Ray number emitted from the source (e.g. 0->100) and the Reflection number (e.g. 0->10) as it bounces around the scene: (int Ray, int Reflection).

Dictionary Value:
The `SimulationPoint` is an output point of a ray-tracing procedure, the most important element of which is that it contains a field `bool hasHit` that indicates if the point, well, hit an element in the scene or not. (We're looking for those errors here, hence `source.SimulationResult.Where(x=>!x.Value.hashit);`) (FWIW, this `struct SimulationPoint` also contains the Ray & Reflection data.)

Generally, this works. But I really like the LINQ syntax and one-liner concept, as it can avoid multiple nested loops. Does anyone have an idea how this can be simplified using the LINQ extensions?

Please keep in mind that I'd like to be able to jump around at the user's choice within the `sl` collection, this is the problem I'm having with the `IGrouping<int, SimulationPoint>` outputs from the `GroupBy(x=>x.Key.Item2, x=>x.Value)` method - it's only accessible sequentially using a `foreach` loop, even when ordering it with `OrderBy(x.Key.Item2).ThenBy(x.Key.Item1)`.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The SortedList constructor accepts a dictionary of the key/values to add to the list. You should be able to just throw that into your linq expression.

Comment: Not that LINQ code doesn't exactly avoid multiple nested loops, but rather it hides them inside methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I sorted it out myself. It turns out I didn't need the SortedLists(s) at all, and since I have access to both the `key.reflection` and `key.ray`, I can just access the `SimulationPoint` directly from the `source.SimulationResult` dictionary.

So, in the end, all I needed was a `List<List<int>>` which is generated like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxrays; i++)
    sl.Add(new List<int>());
foreach (var q in source.SimulationResult.Where(x => !x.Value.hasHit))
    sl[q.Key.Item2].Add(q.Key.Item1);
for (int i = 0; i < maxrays; i++)
    sl[i].Sort();
```

It does make multiple loops, but that seemed unavoidable. The possibly empty child lists are necessary for other processing functions, and to save time, that's why they're all made at once rather than checking if they exist while going through the `foreach` loop. Then, because I want the child list in order, just calling `List<T>.Source()` works great, rather than trying to get LINQ to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding an extension method (group) analogous to `ToDictionary` to do `ToSortedList`. Then with that extension method available, you can use `GroupBy` (which is internally creating a `Dictionary`...) to create the `SortedList`s. Internally you are essentially running over the source data twice, but it doesn't seem like you are talking about a lot of data.

```
var sl2 = q.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key.Reflection) // group by outer SortedList Key
           .ToSortedList(kvpg => kvpg.Key, // outer SortedList Key (Reflection)
                         // outer SortedList Value (SortedList: Ray -> SimulationPoint)
                         kvpg => kvpg.ToSortedList(kvp => kvp.Key.Ray, // inner SortedList Key (Ray)
                                                   kvp => kvp.Value) // inner SortedList Value (SimulationPoint)
                        );
```

Here are the extension method definitions:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static SortedList<TKey, TValue> ToSortedList<TItem, TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TItem> items, Func<TItem, TKey> keyFn, Func<TItem, TValue> valueFn) {
        var ans = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var item in items)
            ans.Add(keyFn(item), valueFn(item));
        return ans;
    }
    public static SortedList<TKey, TValue> ToSortedList<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> items, Func<TValue, TKey> keyFn) {
        var ans = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var item in items)
            ans.Add(keyFn(item), item);
        return ans;
    }
    public static SortedList<TKey, TKey> ToSortedList<TKey>(this IEnumerable<TKey> items) {
        var ans = new SortedList<TKey, TKey>();
        foreach (var item in items)
            ans.Add(item, item);
        return ans;
    }
}
```